# "There is/are twelve items in a dozen" -- verb number agreement in English existential clauses

Tags: agreement

I learned my English grammar pre-CGEL and recently learned that **there** is regarded as a pronoun and as the subject of the verb in constructions like the following, where the verb agrees in number with the noun that follows it:

> There remain traces of a canal system in the jungle.
>
> There remains only the foundation of a grain silo on the long-deserted farmstead.
>
> There are twelve things in a dozen.
>
> There's twelve things in a dozen.
>
> *There is twelve things in a dozen.

Why does the contracted form "There's" admit a singular verb with a plural noun whereas
the uncontracted form "there is" does not?  Why does coalescing "there" with the verb "is" allow the number to disagree?

Comment: Please comment on the downvote so at least I can understand the shortcoming of the question and possibly remedy it.

Comment: I am the down vote and have also voted to close. This question is asking about the grammar of a single language (i.e. English) rather a linguistic question so is, in my view, off-topic, but would be better suited on the English or ELL sites. If reframed more in terms of how to describe this behaviour within a linguistic framework it can probably be made on topic though

Comment: @Tristan Thank you for the clarification. I'm not a frequent visitor here and didn't realize that questions related to a specific language were off-topic.  I'd seen many that specifically reference English. Should I delete the question?

Comment: no need to delete just on my opinion! If enough people agree with me the question will be closed or migrated, but it's possible people will disagree with my interpretatin